# UML Component diagram relationships

Tags: uml

So I came across this component diagram

[image]

for an online shopping system and I wanted to know what relationship is between the customer and account components? Is it right or not? If not what relationship it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the diagram looks a bit confusing. Is it showing assembly Connectors or dependency-wiring between the components? Either way the wiring context is missing.  We could assume that it is the system of interest, that is elsewhere identified as such. I suggest to always show it, though.

Dependency wiring shown with the ball in the socket notation is binary. So the 4-nary `CustomerDetails` is probably an assembly Connector. However, Connectors are not possible in a Class or Component Diagram, but only in a Composite Structure Diagramm. Therefore, the rectangles obviously stand for roles the Components have in the system of interest. As such, they must have a colon in front of their names, to separate the rolename, even if it is missing.

Now that we have established, that the lines are assembly connectors, it becomes obvious that the ports are missing, since the Ball-in-Socket notation is available for connectors of simple ports only. Simple Ports are those, that only offer or require one interface.

It is allowed to connect parts directly without using ports. So, the assembly Connector between `Customer` and `Account` is legal.

A completely different question is, whether it makes sense. When all the other Connectors specify a Port, why is it missing here?